# Best practice for Cognos metadata

Tags: cognos

We have multiple people in multiple departments developing Cognos 7 reports which get deployed to a web server.  Months later, questions come in and we don't know who developed the report, who they developed it for, and what problem it is supposed to solve.

There does not seem to be any place to put this kind of metadata in an .imr file, so we are thinking of creating a template hidden text box.

Have others solved this?

Is there a more standard way?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to use a source control system:

[Configuring a source control system for Cognos Framework Manager metadata](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.c8bizos_ig.8.4.1.doc/t_c8zos_wndwcnfgsrcecontrolsystem.html)